# if $|z-3-2i| \leq 2 , \text{ find the minimum of } |2z-6+5i|$

Tags: complex-numbers

if $|z-3-2i| \leq 2 , \text{ find  the minimum of } |2z-6+5i|$

My attempt:-

Let $z=x+iy$
so we have
$(x-3)^2+(y-2)^2 \leq4$

let $|2z-6+5i |  \text{ be }\phi $

so ${\phi}^2 =4(x-3)^2+(2y+5)^2$

I squared it as the first term is common, however,I'm not sure what to do from here

Working with @Martin R's suggestion,
The region of The first number is a circle given by the cartesian equation $ (x-3)^2+(y-2)^2 \leq 4$
[image]

the point $(3,-2.5)$ lies 2.5 units below the circle, however, my books says the answer is 5,

Comment: I would start with a geometric solution. $z$ lies in the disk $z-3-2i| \leq 2 $, and you are looking for (twice) the minimal distance to the point $3-2.5 i$. – The triangle inequality does also help.

Comment: Would the answer be $\frac{5}{2}$? If not why not(My book says it's 5)

Comment: The book is right (don't forget the factor $2$).

Comment: Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The (reverse) triangle inequality helps: For all $z$ with $|z-3-2i| \leq 2$ is
$$
|2z-6+5i| = 2 \left|z-3+ \frac 52 i\right| = 2 \left| z-3-2i + \frac 92 i \right| \\
\ge 2 \left( \left| \frac 92 i\right| - \left| z-3-2i\right|\right) \\
\ge 2 \left( \frac 92 - 2\right) = 5 \, .
$$
Equality holds for $z=3$.

Geometrically, this is twice (!) the distance from the point $3-\frac 52i$ to the disk centered at $z=3+2i$ with radius $2$.